# Not all photos showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook app that allows users to select one of their facebook photos. To do this I use the Facebook graph API to pull album / photo data to display a list of albums (with name & image count), and then list of all photos when album name is clicked.

I've had feedback that not all images are displaying for an album. For example an album shows a count of 92 pictures but only 20 show up.

I just uploaded 30 timeline photos to my own account to try and replicate this. As a result my timeline photo album shows a count of 30 photos, but only one photo actually shows up in it.

I used the Graph API tool to examine this problem. When doing /me/albums my timeline album shows a 'count' of 30. However, when I do /my-timeline-album-id/photos only 1 photo is listed.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Facebook generally uses paging in their results, which sdk are you using? (PHP, JavaScript, etc.)

Comment: The graph api using the php sdk

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve your edge

```
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
```

after that, the edge will contain metadata for pagination automatically if there is any, so you could use a loop in order to determine if it's "finished"

to retrieve the next "page" of data, simply query your fb again

```
$nextFeed = $fb->next($feedEdge); // This will automatically call the next page in the edge...
```

You can continue this loop until count($nextFeed) == 0

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_pagination_basic